# MassTransit Quartz Scheduling - Will Repeated schedules be supported?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, masstransit, quartz.net-2.0

I have been using MassTransit with Quartz integration and can successfully schedule messages to occur as a single-shot event at some point in the future.
I know that Quartz.Net supports repeated schedules and cannot see a MassTransit extension to hook into this. I think I have 4 options?:

1. Write the extension myself (but lose NuGet updates)
2. Hope that the MassTransit team support this at some point
3. Adjust my consumer to re-schedule the repeated message on each consume (in effect, writing a workaround)
4. Use Quartz.net to adjust the trigger that's been assigned to my scheduled job. I have been able to do this but it seems a bit of a "hack" - there's also threading delay considerations with this.

Any advice welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was discussed on the MassTransit mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/masstransit-discuss/adBZ4Je-ApY/3tkywFDdr5wJ